# More efficient way to get current day of week and run code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, performance

I have an extremely inefficent piece of code here that does a rather simple job - detects what day of the week it is and sets a bunch of text boxes with a string. The code works fine, but i'd assume there's a better way to do this?

```
if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                {
                    time7.Text = "TUESDAY";
                    time8.Text = "WEDNESDAY";
                    time9.Text = "THURSDAY";
                    time10.Text = "FRIDAY";
                    time11.Text = "SATURDAY";
                    time12.Text = "SUNDAY";
                    time13.Text = "MONDAY";
                }
                if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                {
                    time7.Text = "WEDNESDAY";
                    time8.Text = "THURSDAY";
                    time9.Text = "FRIDAY";
                    time10.Text = "SATURDAY";
                    time11.Text = "SUNDAY";
                    time12.Text = "MONDAY";
                    time13.Text = "TUESDAY";
                }
                if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
                {
                    time7.Text = "THURSDAY";
                    time8.Text = "FRIDAY";
                    time9.Text = "SATURDAY";
                    time10.Text = "SUNDAY";
                    time11.Text = "MONDAY";
                    time12.Text = "TUESDAY";
                    time13.Text = "WEDNESDAY";
                }
                if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                {
                    time7.Text = "FRIDAY";
                    time8.Text = "SATURDAY";
                    time9.Text = "SUNDAY";
                    time10.Text = "MONDAY";
                    time11.Text = "TUESDAY";
                    time12.Text = "WEDNESDAY";
                    time13.Text = "THURSDAY";
                }
                if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
                {
                    time7.Text = "SATURDAY";
                    time8.Text = "SUNDAY";
                    time9.Text = "MONDAY";
                    time10.Text = "TUESDAY";
                    time11.Text = "WEDNESDAY";
                    time12.Text = "THURSDAY";
                    time13.Text = "FRIDAY";
                }
                if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                {
                    time7.Text = "SUNDAY";
                    time8.Text = "MONDAY";
                    time9.Text = "TUESDAY";
                    time10.Text = "WEDNESDAY";
                    time11.Text = "THURSDAY";
                    time12.Text = "FRIDAY";
                    time13.Text = "SATURDAY";
                }
                if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    time7.Text = "MONDAY";
                    time8.Text = "TUESDAY";
                    time9.Text = "WEDNESDAY";
                    time10.Text = "THURSDAY";
                    time11.Text = "FRIDAY";
                    time12.Text = "SATURDAY";
                    time13.Text = "SUNDAY";
                }
```

Comment: Verbose and error-prone yes, but not inefficient.

Comment: I'd still like to avoid those two things if possible.

Comment: Something like time7.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper(), time8.Text = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2).DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper() should work?

Comment: Not really any different, just a slightly modified way to do the same exact thing. @AD.Net's awnser solves this problem perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var textBoxes = new List<TextBox>{time7, time8};//add others
var current = DateTime.Now;
foreach(var tb in textBoxes)
{
  current = current.AddDays(1);
  tb.Text = current.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper();
}
```

Something like this, you can also use other variations like `for(var i = 0...)` loop, but you get the idea.

Also, you can use `MVVM` pattern to bind to the `textboxes` which is even easier.

Comment: Working fine and completely non-verbose, which was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1)create array of textbox

2)set a dynamic number (between 0 to 6) to days

3)then fill textboxs by a loop function

```
for(i=0;i<=6:i++)
{textbox[i].text=dynamic_function_in_form_load(i);}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
void YourFunction()
{
    // a list of your day-names: since it seems that you are maintaining some old code, I presume that implementation of localization is out of question, so you can use a list..
    var dateNames = new List<string>() { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };

    // a list of your textboxes that hold names of days
    var tbs = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7 };

    // current day
    var x = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

    shift(dateNames, tbs, x);
}

void shift(List<string> dates, List<TextBox> tbs, int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        dates.Insert(7, dates[0]);
        dates.Remove(dates[0]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count; i++)
    {
        tbs[i].Text = dates[i];
    }
}
```

It's not "nice" but still easier to maintain than what you have now.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var labels =
    typeof(DayOfWeek).GetEnumNames()
        .Concat(typeof(DayOfWeek).GetEnumNames())
        .Skip((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + 1)
        .Take(7)
        .Select(x => x.ToUpperInvariant())
        .ToArray();

 time7.Text = labels[0];
 time8.Text = labels[1];
 time9.Text = labels[2];
 time10.Text = labels[3];
 time11.Text = labels[4];
 time12.Text = labels[5];
 time13.Text = labels[6];
```